Linking an external shared object in Android Studio
I'm writing an app in C++, that is using SDL2.
I've added the headers to the app/cpp/include directory of the project.
I've also downloaded the source code from Github and compiled it into an Android shared object, but I can't get the linker in Android Studio to find it.
Solutions online suggest creating a jniLibs folder in the app directory, and place there all the shared objects, but that doesn't work.
That's my CMakeList.txt file:
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html.
# For more examples on how to use CMake, see https://github.com/android/ndk-samples.

# Sets the minimum CMake version required for this project.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

# Declares the project name. The project name can be accessed via ${ PROJECT_NAME},
# Since this is the top level CMakeLists.txt, the project name is also accessible
# with ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} (both CMake variables are in-sync within the top level
# build script scope).
project("easynes_android")

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.
#
# In this top level CMakeLists.txt, ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} is used to define
# the target library name; in the sub-module's CMakeLists.txt, ${PROJECT_NAME}
# is preferred for the same purpose.
#
# In order to load a library into your app from Java/Kotlin, you must call
# System.loadLibrary() and pass the name of the library defined here;
# for GameActivity/NativeActivity derived applications, the same library name must be
# used in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

# Find all .cpp files in the current directory
file(GLOB CPP_SOURCE_FILES "*.cpp")

# Find all .c files in the current directory
file(GLOB C_SOURCE_FILES "*.c")

# Combine the lists of .cpp and .c files
set(SOURCE_FILES ${CPP_SOURCE_FILES} ${C_SOURCE_FILES})

# Add the library using the collected source files
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link libraries from various origins, such as libraries defined in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or Android system libraries.
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        # List libraries link to the target library
        android
        log
        libSDL2.so)


the jniLibs folder looks like the following:
.../app/jniLibs
--->arm64-v8a
-------> libSDL2.so
--->armeabi-v7a
-------> libSDL2.so
etc...

Thanks in advance
EDIT:
This is the error I'm getting:
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library /home/roeet/AndroidStudioProjects/easynesandroid/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/15i4x120/obj/x86_64/libeasynes_android.so
FAILED: /home/roeet/AndroidStudioProjects/easynesandroid/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/15i4x120/obj/x86_64/libeasynes_android.so 
: && /home/roeet/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=x86_64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=/home/roeet/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++17 -fno-limit-debug-info  -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libeasynes_android.so -o /home/roeet/AndroidStudioProjects/easynesandroid/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/15i4x120/obj/x86_64/libeasynes_android.so CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/apu.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/bus.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/cnrom_3.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/controller.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/cpu.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/instructions.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/mapper_n_cart.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/mmc1_1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/mmc3_4.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/native-lib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/nes_screen.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/nrom_0.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/ppu.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/unrom_2.cpp.o CMakeFiles/easynes_android.dir/utils.cpp.o  -landroid  -llog  -lSDL2  -latomic -lm && :
ld: error: unable to find library -lSDL2
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


Edit your question with the full compile output. also add set(VERBOSE 1) so it prints the full commandline used. I think it is just a matter of telling CMake to consider jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI} when linking..

Managed to fix it:
I updated my CMake file to this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project("easynes_android")

file(GLOB CPP_SOURCE_FILES "*.cpp")
file(GLOB C_SOURCE_FILES "*.c")

set(SOURCE_FILES ${CPP_SOURCE_FILES} ${C_SOURCE_FILES})

# Set path to jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}
set(jniLibs_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI})

# Add the library using the collected source files
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library.
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        android
        log
        ${jniLibs_DIR}/libSDL2.so)

SDL window wont open up though. Still need to figure that one out.
